# Where clause on a Salesforce subquery

Tags: salesforce, soql

I'm running into some trouble filtering my SOQL Query by date where the date field belongs to the child of the object I'm querying.

I couldn't find anything in the documentation, and I tried two different queries, both of which failed:

```
SELECT Name, (SELECT Date__c FROM Child__r) 
FROM Parent Where Date__c >= <todays_date>

SELECT Name, (SELECT Date__c FROM Child__r) 
FROM Parent Where Child__r.Date__c >= <todays_date>
```

Is this even possible in Salesforce?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Its not totally clear from your question exactly what your trying to filter. But if you want to get a list of parents that have a child record with a date matching some critera then you can use a semi-join, e.g.

```
select name from parent where 
      id in (select parentId from child where date__c > :today)
```

You can also add in the child sub query if you want the child data as well e.g.

```
select name, (select someChildFields from child__r) from parent where 
      id in (select parentId from child where date__c > :today)
```

This will get you the parent that have a child with the criteria, and for each parent, get all the children. You can also filter the sub-query on the same criteria if you only want the children that match the criteria, e.g.

```
select name, (select someChildFields from child__r where date__c > :today) 
      from parent where id in (select parentId from child where date__c > :today)
```

Finally, depending on exactly what you're trying to do, you can also flip it around and query the child table directly, pulling in data from the parent record, e.g.

```
select childFields, parent__r.name from child where date__C > :today
```

Comment: Thanks! The second query was what I was looking for. I basically wanted to display a listing of parent objects based on a range of dates (the date field being in the child object).